# Where can I find details of the fields in an Azure AD Audit Log?

Tags: azure-active-directory, audit-logging

We have an application which parses the Audit Logs emitted by Azure AD.  More specifically we are parsing the 'Update application' log to detect when a new Role has been added to an Application (see example below).

We would like to find out more information about the "DirectAccessGrantTypes" and "ImpersonationAccessGrantTypes" fields.  If someone can point us to documentation for this that would be great.

```
[{"EntitlementEncodingVersion":2,"EntitlementId":"654a4f1f-1b7f-4354-a6d6-fcf7346af0ec","IsDisabled":true,"Origin":0,"Name":"Data Manager","Description":"Manager for test app","Definition":null,"ClaimValue":"DataManager","ResourceScopeType":0,"IsPrivate":false,"UserConsentDisplayName":null,"UserConsentDescription":null,"DirectAccessGrantTypes":[20],"ImpersonationAccessGrantTypes":[],"EntitlementCategory":0,"DependentMicrosoftGraphPermissions":[]},{"EntitlementEncodingVersion":2,"EntitlementId":"3d03256d-cf0c-4553-b8af-98d7ebbee1f2","IsDisabled":false,"Origin":0,"Name":"Application Manager","Description":"Admin for test app","Definition":null,"ClaimValue":"ApplicationManager","ResourceScopeType":0,"IsPrivate":false,"UserConsentDisplayName":null,"UserConsentDescription":null,"DirectAccessGrantTypes":[20],"ImpersonationAccessGrantTypes":[],"EntitlementCategory":0,"DependentMicrosoftGraphPermissions":[]},{"EntitlementEncodingVersion":2,"EntitlementId":"88d0d3e3-b661-4760-aea3-f4548db1ff96","IsDisabled":false,"Origin":0,"Name":"Read","Description":"Allow users to add a admin consent","Definition":null,"ClaimValue":"Read","ResourceScopeType":0,"IsPrivate":false,"UserConsentDisplayName":null,"UserConsentDescription":null,"DirectAccessGrantTypes":[],"ImpersonationAccessGrantTypes":[{"Impersonator":29,"Impersonated":20}],"EntitlementCategory":0,"DependentMicrosoftGraphPermissions":[]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

From article > [View reports & logs in entitlement management - Azure AD | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-reports)

> When Azure AD receives a new request, it writes an audit record, in
> which the Category is `EntitlementManagement` and the Activity is
> typically User requests access package assignment. In the case of a
> `direct assignment` created in the Azure portal, the Activity field of
> the audit record is `Administrator directly assigns user to access package`, and the user performing the assignment is identified by the
> ActorUserPrincipalName.

Application Impersonation  is basically  an administrator-managed, not user-managed permission.
Impersonate access grants logs gives information ex:count., of users given  consent by the admin to access the application  to impersonate user.

ImpersonationAccessGrantTypes gives count or info of access grants by admin on behalf of  user whereas DirectAccessGrantTypes gives info about the users who directly access the application ,as they are already assigned by admin.

Reference:
[Multiple Client applications authorisation to WebApi (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f344e748-2c92-4c57-aeff-a6227a8d6535/multiple-client-applications-authorisation-to-webapi)